# Почему не работает тип chkpass в PostgreSQL 9.6.2?

Tags: postgresql

Пытаюсь использовать тип `chkpass` для хранения паролей как прадлагается [здесь](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/chkpass.html). Но при попытке выполнить `create table test (p chkpass)`, получаю:

```
ERROR:  type "chkpass" does not exist
LINE 1: create table test (p chkpass);
```

Почему так происходит и как это исправить?

`select version()` выдает `PostgreSQL 9.6.2 on x86_64-apple-darwin...` версия должна поддерживать...

Comment: _The encryption uses the standard Unix function crypt(), and so it suffers from all the usual limitations of that function; notably that only the first eight characters of a password are considered._ -- вы уверены, что это хорошая идея?

Comment: @D-side мне кажется мало кто использует пароли длинее 8 символов...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это модуль и его надо установить еще. Делается это запросом

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS chkpass;
```

Дока https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.6/sql-createextension